# How do I add whitespace to a concat preprocessor macro?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Given the below, how can I get something that yields `ONE TWO THREE`? I can't seem to figure out what to put in `??` to yield the intended concat behavior. You can't seem to `#define` a single space.

```
#include <iostream>
#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define STRINGIFYMACRO(y) STRINGIFY(y)

#define CONCAT2(X,Y) X ##  Y
#define CONCAT(X,Y) CONCAT2(X,Y)

#define CAT \
ONE     \
TWO


#define DOG \
THREE

#define BAT CONCAT(CONCAT(CAT,?? ),DOG)

int main()
{
    std::cout << STRINGIFYMACRO(BAT) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First stringify, then concatenate strings. Not the other way around. You can't have a token with a whitespace, but you can have a string with it.

Comment: `#ifdef __cplusplus` / `#error wrong compiler` / `#endif`

Comment: Hint: `char *str = "one" " " "two" " " "three";` is the same as `char *str = "one two three";`

Comment: `#define BAT CAT DOG`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `##` operator is used to combine two consecutive *tokens*. It cannot be used to combined things that are not tokens (such as whitespace), nor can it be used if the result is not a valid (preprocessing) token.

In other words, *don't use `##` to combine strings*. That's not what it is for, and it won't work.

Remember that in C++, consecutive strings will be concatenated by the compiler. So there is normally no need to concatenate the contents of the string. Even if you had to concatenate the contents, you could do that without token concatenation because the contents of a string are not a token. (This is only necessary if you are trying to create a computed `#include` filename from multiple components.)

One other useful thing to know is that whitespace inside a macro replacement (not at either end) is reduced to a single space character, which is preserved by the stringify operator.

So if you're OK with the single space character, you can just do this:

```
#include <iostream.h>
#define STRINGIFY(x) #x
#define STRINGIFY_EXPANDED(x) STRINGIFY(x)

#define CAT ONE TWO
#define DOG THREE
#define BAT CAT DOG

int main() {
  std::cout << STRINGIFY_EXPANDED(BAT) << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc1BC4IwGMbx@z7FCx7UQ9BZJbC2zMsMG1QQiMwVg5wyJwjRZ1/zIkFd/8/v5eV9v3pwbq0nFX@OjYBEdoPRom43yGvEXSoBJ1bmNMv312AKwZt@e0Uux5RigmfwrdFidymDghJg52JpuMiAHUpClrJ1apZuQUgqA20tVRDCCwEMpoki3o0GkuTfa3cbzpN/U37svBZm1ArWMXpb@wE)

Otherwise, you could stringify in pieces and concatenate the pieces as desired:

```
#define DOG STRINGIFY(ONE) "   " STRINGIFY(TWO)
#define CAT STRINGIFY(THREE)
#define BAT DOG "\t" CAT
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcxBC4IwFMDx@z7FQw@6Q9BZJbBc5kXDhAoEkblikFN0ghB99jU7qNDh8eD9fzzatpsnpUqZXNDXUDHweNPLjpX1DpkVe3DB4JKlURxGx7s9YjDH/3tBbmc/DkgwgbVGsw2ScFWSmGAwAPQsx@ya4Nkf/GydTikhS9zrOD00cmlMEiEuJNQlFzaGNwLoZeU4tBkkeN5P62XlwnJ165gcOgFbF32U@gI)